# Export Data Definition Script from an Oracle Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle10g

I am new at working with oracle, my only experience is in sql server. In SQL server you can right click a table and say export create script. I need that for Oracle, specifically 10g. Is there a way via GUI or sql command that can accomplish this?

Comment: How are you accessing the Oracle instance - with PLSQL Developer, Toad, SQLPlus, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling dbms_metadata.get_ddl is one option.

e.g.

```
SET LONG 10000 

SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'MY-TABLE-NAME')
FROM dual;
```

Alternatively a number of GUI tools including TOAD and Enterprise Manager have DDL generators.

Answer (score 0):

More general solution would be to dump filtered list of tables, but also other types of objects by using all_objects and all_users views. Example that **works for me**:

```
select dbms_metadata.GET_DDL(u.object_type,u.object_name, u.owner)
from  all_objects u
where 1=1
and u.object_type in ('TABLE', 'INDEX', 'FUNCTION', 'PROCEDURE', 'VIEW', 
                      'TYPE', 'TRIGGER', 'SEQUENCE')
and u.object_name not like 'SYS_%'
and owner in (
  select username from dba_USERS where DEFAULT_TABLESPACE not like 'SYS%' 
  and username not in ('ORACLE_OCM')
  and username not like '%$%'
  )
;
```

References:

- oracle [dbms_metadata.GET_DDL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm#i1019414) function
- oracle [all_objects](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2005.htm) view